# Text goes in two lines in <select> option

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone I have a very strange bug - Text in select option goes in two lines see screenshot (Only in IE8 and IE7 ) Does anyone know solution ?

You can access this table on web topairlines.info and choose tab registration (Please open with IE7 or IE8 to see the bug)
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/DVyVj/1/

```
<table class="form-tabs" width="780" border="0px">
            <tr>
                <td class="td-right"><span class="red-star">*</span>שם פרטי:</td>
                <td><input style="width: 250px; height:30px;" type="text" name="#"></td>
                <td class="td-right"><span class="red-star">*</span>שם משפחה:</td>
                <td><input style="width: 250px; height:30px;" type="text" name="#"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-right">תחום עסק:</td>
                <td><input style="width: 250px; height:30px;" type="text" name="#"></td>
                <td class="td-right"><span class="red-star">*</span>דוא"ל:</td>
                <td><input style="width: 250px; height:30px;" type="text" name="#"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-right"><span class="red-star">*</span>טלפון:</td>
                <td class="td-left"> 
                 <div class="select-right-tabs">
                     <select style="width: 75px; height:34px;">
                         <option value="1">054</option>
                         <option value="2">055</option>
                         <option value="3">056</option>
                         <option value="4">057</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="input-left-tabs">
                    <input style="width: 169px; height:30px;" type="text" name="#">
                 </div>
                </td>
                <td class="td-right">נייד:</td>
                <td class="td-left"> 
                 <div class="select-right-tabs">
                     <select style="width: 75px; height:34px;">
                         <option value="1">054</option>
                         <option value="2">055</option>
                         <option value="3">056</option>
                         <option value="4">057</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="input-left-tabs">
                    <input style="width: 169px; height:30px;" type="text" name="#">
                 </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-right">הערות:</td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <textarea class="textarea-tabs"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-right"></td>
                <td class="extra-table-text">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="#" value="#">מעוניין/ת לקבל בדוא’’ל עדכונים לגבי אירועים
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="last-obligatory td-left">* שדות חובה למילוי</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="td-left">
                    <button type="button" onclick="switchImg('../img/arrow/png')">שלח</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Seems fine on IE7 in my system. Maybe your resolution is small?

Comment: yep it's very strange sometimes it looks fine but if you refresh it looks bad again (1680*1050). Which is yours version of IE?

Comment: Did you try to use `padding-right` on your `select`?

Comment: yep, I've tried 'padding-right' without any positive result

Comment: @AndrewCeban I tested your **HTML** in IE7 and IE8 and it works. Can you post your **CSS**?

Comment: it's too hard to identify CSS that is exactly applied to this table that is why I moved it directly on my FTP, please see [link](http://www.topairlines.info) "**registration**" tab

Answer (score 0):

I think its due to the height is 34px; and if you do not specify explicit style it will take different default style with different line-height;

I think this will do just replace this

```
  <select style="width: 75px; height:30px; line-height:30px;">
```

I have updated the fiddle, pleases refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVyVj/2/) this link,

I hope this will do :)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help too :(

Answer (score 0):

you might try to add **white-space: pre-line;** on option elements!